# Keyboard settings Cherry 6000 French Azerty

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently bought a Cherry 6000 slim keyboard French Azerty layout. I can't seem to get the settings right. Can anyone please tell me which settings I have to use?

Picture of keyboard layout:

[image: Picture of keyboard layout]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: Hey tmmls! Which Ubuntu version are you using?